# Get a percentage column based on another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a payment table looks like below:

```
+--------------+---------+
| Type         | Amount  |
+--------------+---------+
| General      | 500     |
| General      | 700     |
| Assets       | 450     |
| Business     | 270     |
| General      | 70      |
| Assets       | 350     |
+--------------+---------+
```

I want the sum and percentage group by type.

My query is --

```
SELECT fld_type, SUM(fld_amount) FROM tbl_payment group by fld_type


+--------------+---------+
| Type         | Amount  |
+--------------+---------+
| General      | 1270    |
| Assets       | 800     |
| Business     | 270     | 
+--------------+---------+
```

I just getting the sum but can't calculate percentage by sum of amount in this case 2340, and calulate with each group item, such as for general -

1270*100/2340 = 56.27

like this --

```
+--------------+---------+----------+
| Type         | Amount  | Percent% |
+--------------+---------+----------+
| General      | 1270    |   54.27  |
| Assets       | 800     |   34.19  |
| Business     | 270     |   11.54  |
+--------------+---------+----------+
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the percentage for each group you could do it like

```
select fld_type, 
sum(fld_amount),
(sum(fld_amount) / t.total) * 100 percent
from tbl_payment 
cross join (
select sum(fld_amount) total from tbl_payment
) t
group by fld_type
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e41f4b/3)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. one thing is it good to use cross join or ','?

Comment: depends on query optimizer but to get the percentage you need the total first you can do it like cross join or by doing a sub query i prefer the cross join syntax

Answer (score 2):

try this statement

```
SELECT type,sum(amount),sum(amount)*100/(select sum(amount) from tbl_payment) FROM `tbl_payment` group by type
```